# Better to load javascript navigation hierarchy all at once or level by level?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, navigation, hierarchy

I am working on some custom jQuery/javascript navigation for a site and I am curious about the performance implications of a design decision.

The way it works is for every option there are up to 8 child options, this hierarchy can go 4 levels deep.  I believe this makes for 8^4 or 4096 possible navigation items (probably less but this is the max).  These relationships are defined on the server side.

Currently I am working with test data, so there are only about 50 navigation items.  When the page loads, I create every navigation item and then only display what is needed for the current selection.

Should I consider rewriting this to only load the items that are needed when a selection is made via an AJAX call or something?  I am concerned that my current approach may not scale well if it goes up to 4096 navigation items.

Comment: It's pretty hard to answer this without a better sense of exactly how your system works. For example, are you creating all the DOM elements up front, or only when the nav is expanded? Would you need to load 4096 elements from the server via JSON, or are many of them dynamically created?

Comment: This depends on the *expected* size of the site's navigation, more than the theoretical maximum: most site's navigations are nowhere *near* thousands of items (and honestly, if your site has 4 levels of navigation with 4096 items in total, that is a total UX nightmare). If you're *really* worried about this, you could load several topmost levels statically, and then load the rest through AJAX as needed.

Comment: @Piskvor, I don't expect them to hit the maximum, but I still expect them to be pretty large.  My use of "navigation" might also be a bit misleading.  Only leaf items will actually take someone somewhere and leaves may be reused...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If having 4096 navigation items is a real possibility then you'll have to do something like what you're describing.  Simply loading the items into the DOM will take considerable time and further processing will cause greater delays and a poor experience.

For a small number of items, it probably isn't worth your while to over-engineer the solution.  However, the performance gains on a large number of items would be expected to be significant.

Here is an example of on-demand loading in a [Telerik Treeview](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/treeview/examples/programming/loadondemandmodes/defaultcs.aspx). I'm not advocating purchasing the controls (great controls but expensive) however it is an excellent example of what is possible.  Coding this on your own wouldn't be difficult to do and, as you can see, makes for a great user experience.

My two cents: if you have the time, do it now before things get even more complicated/difficult to do later.

Answer (score 1):

Downloading them all at the same time is definitely an option, though loading them into the DOM is another story.  If you really reach the 4096 possibility limit, you can be looking at pushing down 1-2 megabytes a page load (not to much considering image sizes).  Unless you are looking at more data (maybe 16 nodes, 8 levels deep 16^8), then it would be a valid concern.

you could always load 2 deep (8^2 = 64), then when they open a panel, load everything for that panel.  The second layer they need to click through *should* give you enough time to load the rest of the values.

Comment: +0 overall: -1 for 1 million extra bytes per page load; that is definitely too much - especially since images are only loaded *once*. +1 for "preload one level ahead", that hides the wait time.

Comment: I'll take what I can get, could you expand on the 'images only loaded once'?

Comment: Most servers in default configuration (Apache, IIS) will send caching headers with static elements (e.g. images), which help the browser in determining whether they need to be loaded from the server every time, or whether the local copy is sufficient. Dynamically generated JS doesn't have caching support by default and it is rarely added by the implementor, thus most AJAX requests are made on each page load, even though a cached version would suffice.

Comment: A very good point, I haven't ajax in years, and hope browsers were smarter than that (same js file through 3 loads, don't really need to get it again, do we?).